# Degree doesnt get calculated correctly, where did i go wrong?

Tags: java, math, coordinates

Im writing a program, that takes 3d coordinates and places them on a 3d globe, projected onto a 2d screen. To turn the coordinates around an axis, i wanted to use the normal of the two points (start- and end- point (of the flight)), to turn it onto the x3 axis and then turn the rest of the points in the same manner, to eventually calculate the points, that i need to animate a point, that goes from point A to point B. the matrix I use to put the points onto the globe is:

```
    public double[] genXYZ(double phi, double theta) {
    double[] coords3D = new double[3];
    phi = Math.toRadians(phi);
    theta = Math.toRadians(theta);
    coords3D[0] = Math.cos(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
    coords3D[1] = Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
    coords3D[2] = Math.sin(theta);
    return coords3D;
}
```

everything works just fine. Until I try to calculate the phi and theta angles of the normal (after I calculate the normal correctly).

```
public double[] getNAngles(double[] ncoords) {
    double[] NAngles = new double[2];
    NAngles[1] = Math.asin(Math.toRadians(ncoords[2]));
    NAngles[0] = Math.acos(ncoords[0] / Math.cos(NAngles[1]));
    NAngles[0] = Math.toDegrees(NAngles[0]);
    NAngles[1] = Math.toDegrees(NAngles[1]);
    System.out.println("N phi: " + NAngles[0]);
    System.out.println("N theta: " + NAngles[1]);
    return NAngles;
}
```

[Globe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgXq2.png)

Cyan: start (Greenwich)
Magenta: end (Istanbul)
Black: normal
Pink: what the code calculated, what angles black has.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Math.toRadians` call because `coords` are not angles, they are dimensionless values in range `-1..1`

```
NAngles[1] = Math.asin(ncoords[2]);
```

Also consider using `atan2` function for `NAngles[0]` calculation to exclude sign effects and arccosine angle limit (`0..Pi`).

```
NAngles[0] = Math.atan2(ncoords[1], ncoords[0]);
```

Comment: i removed the toRadians with ncoords2 and did the atan2. I'll look atan2 up. Still doesnt seem to add up...

Comment: Do you use `coords[]` returned by `genXYZ` and get another `phi, theta` values?